# Draw a shape "inside" another one

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'd like to draw a shape (with right only angles) inside another (with only right angles). The edges should be as close as possible without overlapping.

I can do something by hand, as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [] (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (3, 1) -- (3, 2) -- (0, 2) -- (0, 0);
        \draw [color=red] (0.02, 0.02) -- (0.98, 0.02) -- (0.98, 1.02) -- (2.98, 1.02) -- (2.98, 1.98) -- (0.5, 1.98) --
        (0.5, 1) -- (0.02, 1) -- % Part that diverges
        (0.02, 0.02);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

that produces

[image]

but of course this is not very robust (the "shifting" of 0.02 has to be re-computed if the width change) nor portable. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use `\pgflinewidth`.  See also `\setpgflinewidth`.  Note that the centers of each line go though the points.

Comment: You don't have to use 0.02, you can combine both coordinate systems: `([shift={(\pgflinewidth, \pgflinewidth)}]0,0)` or `($(0,0)+(\pgflinewidth, \pgflinewidth)$)` if you prefer the `calc` library's syntax. (Or see Zarko's answer for a neater approach to this.) `\pgflinewidth` returns the (current) line width of the current path. If your lines have different line widths, you will need to be cautious.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the added precision, @Qrrbrbirlbel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
u/.style = {yshift=#1\pgflinewidth},
s/.style = {xshift=#1\pgflinewidth}
                        ]
\draw   (0, 0) -- (1, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (3, 1) -- (3, 2) -- (0, 2) -- cycle;
\draw[color=red] 
        ([u,s] 0,0) -| ([u,s=-] 1,1) -| ([u=-,s=-] 3,2) 
                    -| ([u=-] 0.5,1) -| cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can draw black lines on the same way As I draw red one (using `-|` for orthogonal coordinates which shorten code significantly).

Comment: This seems to be working exactly as intended as far as I can  tell. I'll test some more & report, but thanks already!

Comment: @Clément, any news? What is result of your testing?

Comment: Thanks for the ping. It is amazing, exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot!